# Как сопоставить 2 двумерных массива по ключам и сложить их значения?

Tags: php

```
$arr = [
  1500005 => ['1204' => ['volume' => 12]],
  1500007 => ['1384' => ['volume' => 42]],
  1500012 => ['1401' => ['volume' => 8]],
];
$arr2 = [
  1500005 => ['1204' => ['volume' => 46]],
  1500007 => ['1384' => ['volume' => 12]],
  1500016 => ['1774' => ['volume' => 2]],
];

// Сопоставить 2 двумерных массива по ключам и сложить значение ключа 'volume'
// Ниже то что должно получиться

$result = [
  1500005 => ['1204' => ['volume' => 58]],
  1500007 => ['1384' => ['volume' => 54]],
  1500012 => ['1401' => ['volume' => 8]],
  1500016 => ['1774' => ['volume' => 2]],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось самому решить задачку, вдруг кому то понадобится, но незнаю как решить проблему если в `$arr` будет ключей больше

```
$arr = [
  1500005 => ['1204' => ['volume' => 12]],
  1500007 => ['1384' => ['volume' => 42]],
  1500012 => ['1401' => ['volume' => 8]],
];
$arr2 = [
  1500005 => ['1204' => ['volume' => 46]],
  1500007 => ['1384' => ['volume' => 12]],
  1500016 => ['1774' => ['volume' => 2]],
];

foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value) {
  if (isset($arr[$key])) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $data) {
      if (isset($arr[$key][$key2])) {
        $arr[$key][$key2] = [
          'volume' => $arr[$key][$key2]['volume'] + $data['volume']
        ];
      } else $arr[$key][$key2] = $data;
    }
  } else $arr[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: сделайте пустой массив и сначала туда добавьте всё из одного, а потом из другого массива - это решит проблему с наличием/отсутствием ключей